# Allowing a user to manually run a scheduled program from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As part of my web application I have a program that runs periodically during low activity times. However I want to allow the functionality to the user to be able to start the program manually. How can I do this? Where should I put my ruby program within the rails framework and how do I offer a link to commence the program then redirect to another page while the test is running. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code could be put in any controller but if you want the program to run quietly behind the scene without blocking your browser (pretty logic spec), you should trigger it using some tool like `DelayedJob` or `Resque`.
[Great Railscasts here](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=delayed).

Comment: to add on, addressing the "where" part of the question...I heard someone saying to put the job objects somewhere in the lib directory, but I also heard someone else say to create a jobs directory under the app dir. My project has already gone down the first path but I like the second approach